# Only get Tweets that mention a country

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

Is it possible to exclusively gather Tweets which mention countries by name? I am only gathering Tweets from the US.

I know that Twitter allows us to access `context_annotations` from the payload, and that `context_annotations` identifies if a tweet mentions a country. Here, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/annotations/overview ,they mention that  `countries` is domain number 160 in `context annotations`.

I'm wondering if it is possible to exclusively gather Tweets that mention country names. I am not familiar with Tweepy, so I've finally managed to obtain Tweets from the US, but am still unable to specify the code to obtain only tweets which mention countries.

This is my current code:

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

# Specify Query
query = ' "favorite country" place_country:US'                   
start_time = '2022-03-05T00:00:00Z' 
end_time = '2022-03-11T00:00:00Z' 

tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at', 'geo'], 
                                  
                                  place_fields = ['place_type','geo'], expansions='geo.place_id',
                                  start_time=start_time,
                                  end_time=end_time, max_results=10000)




# Prepare to write to csv file
f = open('tweetSheet.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

# Write to csv file
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.created_at)
    writer.writerow(['0', tweet.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.text])

# Close csv file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

### has:geo:

One way of doing this would be by filtering in tweets that have country attributes.

You can use the `has:geo:` operator in your query instead of the `place_country:` operator seen in the [Twitter Docs.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location) This way you get all the tweets that are geo tagged, every geo tagged tweet has a country attribute.

### includes

Another way would be checking if the tweet has an `includes` attribute, empty if it has no geo attributes: `response.includes != {}`. To get the country code if needed then `response.includes['places'][0].country` works just fine. It is not very well documented in the [Tweepy Docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_tweet) so here are all the geo attributes found in the [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/place) for a tweet:

```
twt_geo = 1602695447298162689
twt_no_geo = 1602719044645408768

response = client.get_tweet(
    twt_geo, place_fields=['country', 'country_code', 'place_type', 'name'], expansions=['geo.place_id'])

if(response.includes != {}):
    print(response.includes)
    print(response.includes['places'][0].country)
    print(response.includes['places'][0].country_code)
    print(response.includes['places'][0].place_type)
    print(response.includes['places'][0].name)
    print(response.includes['places'][0].full_name)
    print(response.includes['places'][0])
    print(response.data.geo)
    print(response.data.geo['place_id'])
else:
    print(response.data.id)
```

### Hashtags

If you are implying filtering in tweets that have country names as hashtags as country mentions, you can extract the tweet text with `response.data.text` and compare the country names you would like to filter in.